# webpack and kafka-node integration

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

I'm trying to integrate into a HTML file a Javascript written by me. Since script **requires** kafka-node in order to produce something like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node#consumer), I'm trying to use webpack to bundle everything.
I'm using this [getting started](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/) guide and adapting it to my specific case. The only thing I'm changing is `index.js` file, putting my script in there as follows:

```
import _ from 'kafka-node';

document.write("Starting Javascript Kafka Consumer...");

var kafka = require('kafka-node'),
    Consumer = kafka.Consumer,
    client = new kafka.Client("127.0.0.1:2181"),
    consumer = new Consumer( ...

...
```

I'm using same configuration file as published in the above getting started referred link.

I did run `npm install --save-dev webpack` and `npm install --save kafka-node`. This is my output:

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js 
Hash: f2fd34c274324b3ac92a
Version: webpack 3.4.1
Time: 1475ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
bundle.js  1.48 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
   [6] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
  [39] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
  [69] ./src/index.js 890 bytes {0} [built]
 [103] ./node_modules/optional 160 bytes {0} [optional] [built]
 [112] ./node_modules/buffermaker ^.*BufferMaker$ 205 bytes {0} [built]
 [122] ./node_modules/node-zookeeper-client/lib/jute 160 bytes {0} [built]
    + 139 hidden modules

WARNING in ./node_modules/node-zookeeper-client/lib/jute/index.js
771:20-47 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/optional/optional.js
6:11-26 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

ERROR in ./node_modules/kafka-node/lib/client.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/work-xpandit/consumerJS/node_modules/kafka-node/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/kafka-node/lib/client.js 3:10-24
 @ ./node_modules/kafka-node/kafka.js
 @ ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/kafka-node/lib/kafkaClient.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/work-xpandit/consumerJS/node_modules/kafka-node/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/kafka-node/lib/kafkaClient.js 10:12-26
 @ ./node_modules/kafka-node/kafka.js
 @ ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/kafka-node/lib/client.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/home/work-xpandit/consumerJS/node_modules/kafka-node/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/kafka-node/lib/client.js 5:10-24
 @ ./node_modules/kafka-node/kafka.js
 @ ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/kafka-node/lib/kafkaClient.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tls' in '/home/work-xpandit/consumerJS/node_modules/kafka-node/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/kafka-node/lib/kafkaClient.js 12:12-26
 @ ./node_modules/kafka-node/kafka.js
 @ ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/node-zookeeper-client/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/work-xpandit/consumerJS/node_modules/node-zookeeper-client'
 @ ./node_modules/node-zookeeper-client/index.js 19:24-38
 @ ./node_modules/kafka-node/lib/consumerGroupMigrator.js
 @ ./node_modules/kafka-node/lib/consumerGroup.js
 @ ./node_modules/kafka-node/kafka.js
 @ ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/node-zookeeper-client/lib/ConnectionManager.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/home/work-xpandit/consumerJS/node_modules/node-zookeeper-client/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/node-zookeeper-client/lib/ConnectionManager.js 8:10-24
 @ ./node_modules/node-zookeeper-client/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/kafka-node/lib/consumerGroupMigrator.js
 @ ./node_modules/kafka-node/lib/consumerGroup.js
 @ ./node_modules/kafka-node/kafka.js
 @ ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/node-zookeeper-client/lib/jute/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/work-xpandit/consumerJS/node_modules/node-zookeeper-client/lib/jute'
 @ ./node_modules/node-zookeeper-client/lib/jute/index.js 14:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/node-zookeeper-client/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/kafka-node/lib/consumerGroupMigrator.js
 @ ./node_modules/kafka-node/lib/consumerGroup.js
 @ ./node_modules/kafka-node/kafka.js
 @ ./src/index.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/buffermaker/test/BufferMaker.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'should' in '/home/work-xpandit/consumerJS/node_modules/buffermaker/test'
 @ ./node_modules/buffermaker/test/BufferMaker.js 1:0-17
 @ ./node_modules/buffermaker ^.*BufferMaker$
 @ ./node_modules/buffermaker/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/kafka-node/lib/protocol/protocol.js
 @ ./node_modules/kafka-node/lib/protocol/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/kafka-node/kafka.js
 @ ./src/index.js
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Me too, just now. Will post back here if I find a solve.

Comment: Any luck @Ricardo ?  Trying something similar, but so far am unable to have webpack packing node-zookeeper-client.

Answer (score 2):

The way this module's tests are written it depends on `should` as a `devDependency`. NPM dev-dependencies aren't installed in the parent project even if the parent is in dev mode. Just run:

```
npm i -D should
```

Even if you don't use it in your project. This resolves the issue for me. My project had its other requirements such as Mocha already installed. If you're missing any more, you may need to do this for more than one package.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

In cmd/terminal: `npm i -D should`

From the directory node-modules/node-zookeeper-client/lib/jute
Copy the entire contents of specification.json and then in index.js, replace 
this...

```
var specification = require('specification.json');
```

with this...

```
var specification = <CTRL+V (contents of the specification.json file)>
```